# Page breaks when multiple users are used in database

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Im trying to create a page where all completed forms of a certain user role are displayed. It works fine when only one user with that role has completed forms and it displays correctly. However when a second user with the role completes a form it crashes. I tried moving the foreach($users as $user) end } but to no avail. Im a bit clueless of why it would work with 1 user and not the 2nd. It should go through the foreach again and do the whole thing over.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Partner Portal */ ?>
<?php get_header() ?>
    
    <?php
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (in_array('um_5st3ps-admin', $user->roles)) {
    $args = array(
        'role'    => 'um_5st3ps',
        'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    );
    $users = get_users( $args );
    foreach($users as $user){
    $id= $user->ID;
    if ($id != 0) {
            $userMeta = get_user_meta($id);
            foreach ($userMeta as $key => $value) {
                $userMeta[$key] = $value[0];
            }
            $userMeta['submitted'] = unserialize($userMeta['submitted']);
            $full_name = $userMeta['first_name'] . ' ' . $userMeta['last_name'];
            $email = $userMeta['submitted']['user_email'];
    
            global $wpdb;
    
            $getdataempty = "SELECT * FROM wp_tfz8fsycdy_fsq_data WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM wp_tfz8fsycdy_fsq_data  where user_id='".$id."' GROUP BY form_id) AND user_id='".$id."' AND form_id NOT in (94,58,60,55,63,66,65,68,74,72,73,75,76)";
    
            $getdataemptyvalue = $wpdb->get_results($getdataempty);
        
           $getdata = "SELECT * FROM wp_tfz8fsycdy_fsq_data WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM wp_tfz8fsycdy_fsq_data  where user_id='".$id."' GROUP BY form_id) AND user_id='".$id."' AND form_id in (94,58,60,55,63,66,65,68,74,72,73,75,76)";
    
            $getuserdata = $wpdb->get_results($getdata);
        } else {
            wp_redirect('exam-login');
           exit;
        }
        
      $gettabdata = $wpdb->get_results("select * from wp_tfz8fsycdy_fsq_form where id in (58,60,55,63,66,65,68,74,72,73,75,76,94)");
    
        function getexamFormdata($pid)
        {
            global $wpdb;
            $id2 = $pid;
            $frmdata = "select * from wp_tfz8fsycdy_fsq_form where id ='".$id2."' order by name desc";
            $geformabdata = $wpdb->get_results($frmdata);
            $valueformname = $geformabdata[0]->name;
            return $valueformname;
        }
        ?>
    
      
     <div class="exam_box">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <?php       
    $order_statuses = array('wc-completed');
    $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value' => $id,
        'post_status' => $order_statuses,
        'numberposts' => -1
    ) );
    
             foreach($customer_orders as $order ){
                      $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;
                            foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item){
                           
    ?>
    
    <?php }
    }?>
               
    <div class ="col-sm-5">
     <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables" border='1' style="margin-top:20px">
                <thead class="examhead">
    
                    <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                        <th>Exam Name</th>
                        <th>Score/Max Score</th>
                <th>Date of Exam</th>
                        <th>Status of Exam</th>
                            </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                
       <?php if(!empty($getuserdata))foreach($getuserdata as $key=>$value){ ?>
            <?php if(isset($value->id)){ ?> 
                        <tr class="odd gradeX">
                            <td><?php echo $key+1?></td>
                            <td><strong><?php echo getexamFormdata($value->form_id);?></strong></td>
                <td><?php echo $value->score.' / '.$value->max_score;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s A',strtotime($value->date));?></td>
                                                   
                               <?php  $exam_name = getexamFormdata($value->form_id);
                             $score_total = $value->score; 
                                                                                                    
                             if ($score_total > -1) { ?>                                    
                                <td><strong><?php echo 'Completed';?></strong></td>
                     
                               <?php }         
                }                
            }
    }
    }
    } 
    ?>
    </tr>  
                </tbody>
          
          </table>
        </div>
    
    <?php get_footer() ?>
```

Comment: Do you think we really need to see your CSS

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.